# Star Generation - Game Maker

Tags: game-maker, gml

I am making in Game Maker where you are a ship. You stay in the middle of the screen while the stars would move around you, giving the illusion of movement.

So far the spaceship rotates to follow the mouse and when you press the space bar the stars are given the direction and velocity that the ship should have and it is applied to the star.

The mechanic i'm struggling with is generation the stars randomly as you 'move'. It would need to seem as if you were travelling through space and could relocate the same star generation if you flew back to it.

If anyone has any ideas, that would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Could you use something like Perlin noise to do the initial star generation?  

Given location L in your world, you could generate a seed of W width and H height at L, then you could save the random seed value and the time that chunk was created in some data store.

Then you can take the time offset from the created time and apply it to that chunk, which will give you the new positions of all stars created in that cluster.

Comment: I've only just realised how old this thread is, it popped up in my feed, I hope you found an answer :D

Answer (score 0):

you could use a `random_range()` for the star creation, but for having them stay in place forever its a little hard, maybe you could make only 1 room for everything and make a function that only fill the rooms with stars and starts on create (and then deactivate forever) then save the state of the room and voila (idk if im being clear)